# Elastic search multi node cluster using Podman container NoRouteToHostException error

Tags: elasticsearch, podman

I have installed 2 ES podman containers on 2 different servers(primary and secondary)

Primary elasticsearch.yml config:

```yaml
network.host: 0.0.0.0
cluster.name: xyz-es
node.name: node-primary  # On the primary, use 'node-primary', and 'node-secondary' on the secondary
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.16.211.99", "172.18.205.99"] # ["ip_of_primary", "ip_of_secondary"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-primary", "node-secondary"]
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Secondary elasticsearch.yml config

```yaml
network.host: 0.0.0.0
cluster.name: xyz-es
node.name: node-secondary  # On the primary, use 'node-primary', and 'node-secondary' on the secondary
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.16.211.99", "172.18.205.99"] # ["ip_of_primary", "ip_of_secondary"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-primary", "node-secondary"]
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

However , the secondary are unable to copy the data from primary server, when checking the logs  the secondary Elasticsearch node is able to complete the initial handshake with the primary node, but then the follow-up connection fails with a NoRouteToHostException error.

```yaml
{"@timestamp":"2023-10-26T08:36:24.295Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"address [172.16.211.99:9300], node [null], requesting [false] discovery result: [node-primary][10.89.0.9:9300] connect_exception: Failed execution: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No route to host: 10.89.0.9/10.89.0.9:9300: No route to host: 10.89.0.9/10.89.0.9:9300: No route to host", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[node-secondary][generic][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.discovery.PeerFinder","elasticsearch.node.name":"node-secondary","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"xyz-es"}
```

```yaml
{"@timestamp":"2023-10-26T09:19:32.071Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"completed handshake with [{node-primary}{BGp7fx9kTR6Fh6m1pCan2g}{JfFpk5WNSgG0ayvMP8uB8g}{node-primary}{10.89.0.9}{10.89.0.9:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.10.2}{7000099-8100299}] at [172.16.211.99:9300] but followup connection to [10.89.0.9:9300] failed", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[node-secondary][generic][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.discovery.HandshakingTransportAddressConnector","elasticsearch.node.name":"node-secondary","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"xyz-es","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException","error.message":"[node-primary][10.89.0.9:9300] connect_exception","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [node-primary][10.89.0.9:9300] connect_exception\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$ChannelsConnectedListener.onFailure(TcpTransport.java:1154)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener$FailureResult.complete(SubscribableListener.java:285)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.tryComplete(SubscribableListener.java:197)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.setResult(SubscribableListener.java:222)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.onFailure(SubscribableListener.java:141)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4TcpChannel.lambda$addListener$0(Netty4TcpChannel.java:62)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\nCaused by: org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.UncategorizedExecutionException: Failed execution\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.wrapAsExecutionException(SubscribableListener.java:178)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.wrapException(ListenableFuture.java:38)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.10.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.wrapException(ListenableFuture.java:27)\n\t... 18 more\nCaused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No route to host: 10.89.0.9/10.89.0.9:9300\n\t... 21 more\nCaused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No route to host: 10.89.0.9/10.89.0.9:9300\nCaused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:673)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.94.Final/io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
```

if you look at the logs, you can see that the secondary server will contact primary and primary will respond with **the container internal IP** which is not reachable over the network

the Kube.yml:

```yaml
# Save the output of this file and use kubectl create -f to import
# it into Kubernetes.
#
# Created with podman-4.4.1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-10-09T06:58:43Z"
  labels:
    app: xyz-elascitsearch
  name: xyz-elascitsearch
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - eswrapper
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.10.2
    name: engine
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9200
      hostPort: 9200
    - containerPort: 9300
      hostPort: 9300
    resources: {}
    securityContext: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      name: home-xyz-podman-projects-xyz-elascitsearch-config-elasticsearch.yml-host-0
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      name: home-xyz-podman-projects-xyz-elascitsearch-data-host-1
  hostname: xyz-elascitsearch
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /home/xyz/podman/projects/xyz-elascitsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      type: File
    name: home-xyz-podman-projects-xyz-elascitsearch-config-elasticsearch.yml-host-0
  - hostPath:
      path: /home/xyz/podman/projects/xyz-elascitsearch/data
      type: Directory
    name: home-xyz-podman-projects-xyz-elascitsearch-data-host-1
status: {}
```

How to enforce the secondary node to use the seed_hosts IP and not the respond IP ? or is there another configuration i am missing , appreciate anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Add the [publish_host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings) to the config to let other nodes what IP to call and not default to the host which in this case was localhost defaulting to the container IP

```yaml
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: 172.16.211.99
cluster.name: xyz-es
node.name: node-primary  # On the primary, use 'node-primary', and 'node-secondary' on the secondary
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.16.211.99", "172.18.205.99"] # ["ip_of_primary", "ip_of_secondary"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-primary", "node-secondary"]
xpack.security.enabled: false
```